# How do we get from the exponential iv curve of a BJT to the tanh iv curve of a long tailed pair?

Tags: transistors

I have read that a long tailed pair of transistors has a tanh characteristic I,V curve.

How do we get from the exponential function of a single transistor Ie = Ies(e^(Vbe/Vt)-1) to a tanh function of a LTP?

It would be nice to have method of deriving this equation that shows intuitively what is happening in the circuit.

Here are some relationships that should be relevant here. 
sinh(x) = 1/2 e^x - e^-x 
cosh(x) = 1/2 e^x + e^-x 
e^x = sinh(x) + cosh(x) 
tanh = sinh(x)/cosh(x)

I was reading this page about [OTAs](http://www.oldcrows.net/~patchell/SecretsOfOTAs.pdf) from which the images below are taken, it has a description of how to get a function for a LTP, but no mention of the tanh function.

[image: long tailed pair]
[image: I V curve of long tailed pair]

Comment: Does not Grey and Meyer provide this math?

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the relevant books, I am teaching myself online. If I was at university they would have told me what to read. I did a search for Grey and Meyer, it looks relevant.